# OutOfMemoryError while setting the live wallpaper on screen

Tags: android, out-of-memory, live-wallpaper

```
02-15 09:10:02.196: E/dalvikvm-heap(881): Out of memory on a 2162176-byte allocation.
02-15 09:10:02.376: E/AndroidRuntime(881): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-15 09:10:02.376: E/AndroidRuntime(881): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
02-15 09:10:02.376: E/AndroidRuntime(881):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
02-15 09:10:02.376: E/AndroidRuntime(881):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:502)
02-15 09:10:02.376: E/AndroidRuntime(881):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:355)
02-15 09:10:02.376: E/AndroidRuntime(881):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:378)
02-15 09:10:02.376: E/AndroidRuntime(881):  at com.plugai.android.livewallpapers.fishes.ClownFish.<init>(ClownFish.java:20)
02-15 09:10:02.376: E/AndroidRuntime(881):  at com.plugai.android.livewallpapers.Aquarium.addFishes(Aquarium.java:88)
02-15 09:10:02.376: E/AndroidRuntime(881):  at com.plugai.android.livewallpapers.Aquarium.initialize(Aquarium.java:81)
02-15 09:10:02.376: E/AndroidRuntime(881):  at com.plugai.android.livewallpapers.AquariumWallpaperService$AquariumWallpaperEngine.<init>(AquariumWallpaperService.java:20)
02-15 09:10:02.376: E/AndroidRuntime(881):  at com.plugai.android.livewallpapers.AquariumWallpaperService.onCreateEngine(AquariumWallpaperService.java:10)
02-15 09:10:02.376: E/AndroidRuntime(881):  at android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService$IWallpaperEngineWrapper.executeMessage(WallpaperService.java:1034)
02-15 09:10:02.376: E/AndroidRuntime(881):  at com.android.internal.os.HandlerCaller$MyHandler.handleMessage(HandlerCaller.java:40)
02-15 09:10:02.376: E/AndroidRuntime(881):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-15 09:10:02.376: E/AndroidRuntime(881):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-15 09:10:02.376: E/AndroidRuntime(881):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
02-15 09:10:02.376: E/AndroidRuntime(881):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-15 09:10:02.376: E/AndroidRuntime(881):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-15 09:10:02.376: E/AndroidRuntime(881):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-15 09:10:02.376: E/AndroidRuntime(881):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-15 09:10:02.376: E/AndroidRuntime(881):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: fishes take too much RAM for that aquarium.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently the live wallpaper requires more memory(RAM) than you have.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting an OutOfMemory exception. This means that your app tries to allocate too much Memory in the Device RAM.It is usually caused by trying to load images that are larger than required.

Try scaling down any graphics you use in your live wallpaper.